# Loop not looping inside array & comparing elements of an array

Tags: javascript

In this function I am trying loop into an array, and then return the following thing: if the year is formed by all different digits, then it's a happy year and should be stored where it belongs, in the **happy** array. If not, it should go in the **notHappy** array.

Now the problems:

1) The **IF** condition I tried returns nothing, `[]`. I am quite sure it's not the right way of doing it.

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= t.length; i++) {
if (i[0] != i[1] && i[0] != i[2] && i[0] != i[3]) {
        o.happy.push(i++);
    } else { 
        o.notHappy.push(i++)
    }
    }
```

2) I tried the same loop with a simple `i%2 === 0` condition and I found out that the loop ignores my **arr** altogether and returns `[0, 2, 4]` instead of the actual numbers. It's like it would start looping from `0` itself. How come?

```
function nextHappyYear(arr){
    var o = {
        happy: [],
        notHappy: []
    };

    var t = arr.map(e => e.toString().split(""));

    for (var i = 0; i <= t.length; i++) {
        if (i%2 === 0) {
            o.happy.push(i++);
        } else { o.notHappy.push(i++)}
    }

    return console.log(o.happy)
}  

nextHappyYear([1021, 1022, 1023, 1024]) // returns [0, 2, 4] instead of [1022, 1024]
```

Comment: In the first code example you are checking the index var and not the year array. In the second code you are pushing to the array the var i and not the year (var t). Also notice that you increment the index inside the for loop which is very bad practice

Comment: What @David has commented looks correct

Comment: @DavidWinder thanks for your comment mate. In the 1st one, what do you mean exactly that I am checking the index var and not the year array? Something like if (t[0] != t[1] && t[0] != t[2] && t[0] != t[3])?     This would return me NaN at  the moment. In the second code, if I increment the index outside the loop, how do I "close" the for loop in the first place? Thanks

Comment: I meant exactly what you write- t[0] != t[1] ... check your array construction to find your NaN issue. 
I didn't mean to increment index outside the loop - the for loop increment index with the i++ in her first line -> you need to remove the ++ from the i in the push command.
Also notice that you check for t[0] != t[1] ... doesn't check that all digit are different- consider case as 2444

Comment: Solved :) thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues

**1-for (var i = 0; i <= t.length; i++)**

Arrays indexes start from 0 and ends with `length - 1`. So your condition `i <= t.length` makes an error. Change it to `i < t.length`.

**2-if (i%2 === 0)**

This is not your question condition. You must get all digits in a year and check equality of them.

**3-o.happy.push(i++);**

This part have 2 problem. First, you push into `happy` array the index of that year, not the year. Second, `i++` increase `i` by one and one year will get skipped!

**4-if (i[0] != i[1] && i[0] != i[2] && i[0] != i[3])**

You check just the first digit with others and you don't check second with third and fourth, third digit with forth also.

---

Try this

```js
function hasDuplicate(arr) {
  arr.sort()
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] == arr[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function happyYear1(arr) {
  var o = {
    happy: [],
    notHappy: []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!hasDuplicate((arr[i] + '').split(""))) {
      o.happy.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      o.notHappy.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return o;
}

var output = happyYear1([1021, 1022, 1023, 1024]); // returns [0, 2, 4] instead of [1022, 1024]

console.log(output);
```